# NSMutableAttributedStringを使用し、UILabelで複数行表示させると、…（三点リーダ）が表示されない

Tags: ios, objective-c

TableViewCell上にUILabelを設置し、
Lineを３行固定とし、
LineBreakModeをTrancateTailで設定して、
JSONで可変長の文字を表示させようとしています。

ですが、４行以上になる場合、省略文字の三点リーダ（…）が表示されてくれません。
以下のように、行間を指定したい意図がありまして、このようにしているのですが、
どうにもできません。
ラベルの上に三点リーダのみ自分で付け加える方法も検討したのですが、
綺麗に３行目の文字が切れる前の最終文字の座標も取れないと思っており、、、
お知恵をお貸し頂けないでしょうか。。。

宜しくお願いします。

```
// カスタムLineHeightを指定
CGFloat customLineHeight = 19.0f;

// パラグラフスタイルにlineHeightをセット
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragrahStyle.minimumLineHeight = customLineHeight;
paragrahStyle.maximumLineHeight = customLineHeight;

// NSAttributedStringを生成してパラグラフスタイルをセット
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:printLabel];
[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                       value:paragrahStyle
                       range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

self.printLabel.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Answer (score 1):

まさかとは思うんだがスタイルで改行モードを指定せずラベルに指定してないか？

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragrahStyle.minimumLineHeight = customLineHeight;
paragrahStyle.maximumLineHeight = customLineHeight;
paragrahStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail; // 追加
```

Comment: すみません、ありがとうございます。
その通りで、無事に省略文字が付与されました。

原因は２つでした。
1.その前にラベルを使用していた為、TrancateTailの設定をUILabel側のみにしていたので、問題ないと思っていた。（.xib側に設定）
2.NSMutableParagraphStyleにもlineBreakModeが存在することを知らなかった。

大変助かりました。